# Depth First search in Objective C iphone

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I would like to do a DFS in objetive C. Given the root node which is a view controller and this view controller has an array of children which are view controllers as well. Each of these children could have multiple children and so no and so forth. I would like to visit each view controller starting from the root node once.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you want ideas about? Yes, you can do a depth first search. The object type does not seem relevant.

Comment: What have you tried?  Why do you think a DFS in Objective-C would be any different from one in any other language?

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive method is all you need:

```
- (void)processViewController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    for (UIViewController *child in controller.childViewController) {
        [self processViewController:child];
    }

    // process "controller" here
}
```

To kick it off:

```
UIViewController *root = ... // some view controller
[self processViewController:root];
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew my code is not perfect but what you think about this?

```
#pragma mark - Stack 

@interface Stack : NSMutableArray
- (id)push:(id)item;
- (id)pop;
- (void)clear;
@end

#pragma mark - Interface of 'Node'

@interface Node : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *linkedNodesSet;
@end
```

Depth first search method - (Just for the simplicity, no arguments)

```
- (void)dfs
{
    id rootNode = nil;

    NSMutableSet *visitedNodes = [NSMutableSet setWithObject:rootNode];
    Stack *stack = [[Stack alloc] init];
    [stack push:rootNode];

    while (stack.count > 0)
    {
        NSSet *linkedNodes = ((Node *)stack.lastObject).linkedNodesSet;

        if (!linkedNodes)
        {
            [stack pop];
            continue;
        }

        if ([self isEveryLinkedNodeVisited:linkedNodes
                       fromVisitedNodesSet:visitedNodes])
        {
            [stack pop];
            continue;
        }

        Node *node = linkedNodes.anyObject;

        if (![visitedNodes containsObject:node])
        {
            [visitedNodes addObject:node];
            [stack push:node];

            continue;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)isEveryLinkedNodeVisited:(NSSet *)linkedNodes
             fromVisitedNodesSet:(NSMutableSet *)visitedNodesSet
{
    for (Node *node in linkedNodes)
    {
        if (![visitedNodesSet containsObject:node])
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I know it's working but, actually I want to optimize these codes with the recursive way, but  don't know how in OBJC.